# adding a variable in a list on a dictionary (Dictionary<Key , List<var>) unity C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, unity-game-engine, collections

heres what i want

collection of pc components
then grouped to pc components like ram,storage,gpu,cpu,psu,etc. and they are the keys
then every inside of them theres multiple objects of the same kind

ex.
ram->kingston,adata,hyperx  |  storage->WD,segate
u get the point

my problem is how to add values in the list

example adding intel(var) to cpu(list) to pc components(collection)

its easy to do this in java, because here's how you do it in Map

```
Map<Key,List<string>> map = new Hashmap<key,object>();
map.put(pcComp.ComponentType).add("kingston");
```

but in C# unity your gonna put both the key and the value like this

```
Components.Add(pcComp.ComponentType,new List<>)
```

btw the `pcComp.ComponentType` is a enum

and also what if theres a content inside of the list

`new List<>` wont work right because it will get replaced?

Comment: bad explanation sry idk how to phrase this :)

Comment: new List<string> myList = new List<string>(); Components.Add(pcComp.ComponentType,new List<>); myList.Add("abc");  It doesn't matter where you add abc.   myList is like a pointer and values can be added any place after the constructor.

Comment: but what if theres values inside the list of the collection? it will get replaced right? @jdweng

Comment: myList["cpu].Add(someCpu); this will add a cpu without removing others.

Comment: oh u can treat a arraylist and collection as an ordinary array?? what!? thanks for the help then!!, i came from java thats why idk thats possible

Comment: I made the List<> a string.  You can use any object, not just a string.  So Everts code is getting an existing items from the dictionary.  I would do in two steps var myList = map["key"].  Then myList.Add(new item);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to @jdweng and @Events
you can do this instead

```
Components[pcComp.ComponentType].Add(pcComp.name);
```

you can treat collections and arraylist as an ordinary array

unlike java

```
Arraylist.get(0) ir Arraylist.add(var)
```

Comment: Proper way would be with TryGetValue for safe and fast code but you got the idea.